# Is there a way to run a JS program when building a Java program using Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

Just like how node app.js in the terminal can run a javascript program, can a java program be used to run a javascript program when building it with Gradle.

Comment: You can use [gradle's `Exec`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) to run node.